# Inputting sets of numbers in java - Null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Integer;
public class points{
    private class Vertex{
        public int xcoord,ycoord;
        public Vertex right,left;
    }    
    public points(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int no_of_pts = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        Vertex[] polygon = new Vertex[no_of_pts];        
        for(int i=0;i<no_of_pts;i++){
            String line = input.nextLine();
            String[] check = line.split(" ");           
            polygon[i].xcoord = Integer.parseInt(check[0]);
            polygon[i].ycoord = Integer.parseInt(check[1]);
        }    
    }    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new points();    
    }    
}
```

This is a very simple program in which I want to input n number of points into the system with their x and y co-ordinates

```
Sample Input :
3
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

However after entering "1 2" it throws a NullPointerException . I used Java debug to find the troubling line is

```
polygon[i].xcoord = Integer.parseInt(check[0]);
```

However the check variable correctly shows '1' and '2' . Whats going wrong ?

**EDIT** :
Thanks to the answers, I realized I had to initialize each element of the array to a new object using

```
polygon[i] = new Vertex();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the Vertex reference in the array is null.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Integer;
public class points{
    private class Vertex{
        public int xcoord,ycoord;
        public Vertex right,left;
    }    
    public points(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int no_of_pts = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        Vertex[] polygon = new Vertex[no_of_pts];        
        for(int i=0;i<no_of_pts;i++){
            String line = input.nextLine();
            String[] check = line.split(" "); 
            polygon[i] = new Vertex(); // this is what you need.          
            polygon[i].xcoord = Integer.parseInt(check[0]);
            polygon[i].ycoord = Integer.parseInt(check[1]);
        }    
    }    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new points();    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Yep. where do  you add `new Vertex(...)` objects to the polygon array?

Answer (score 1):

polygon[i] is null as it has not been initialised